# How to force qtcreator use qbs profile?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qbs

I'm working with qtcreator 3.5.0 and custom build of QT 5.5.0
I want to build my project both with qbs & qtcreator.
So, I've created qbs profile, as described in [qbs manual](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/qt-versions.html), and it works well. But I've failed to force qtcreator use this profile. It creates it's own profile, based on mine, but with different name.

```
e.g. `qtc_Desktop-debug` & `qtc_Desktop_0aa29aa9-debug`
```

The problem is that build paths includes profile names. And even if I have completed build by qbs, I need to build all the sources again from qtcreator, if I want to use it.

Comment: In other words, I'm looking for a way to create qtcreator's kit from qbs profile.

Comment: Not sure, if I get you right, but have you looked in tools->Options->Qbs?

Comment: @exilit : yes, certainly

Answer (score 0):

To copy *exactly* build done by QtCreator just copy command displayed in project configuration details (to make thinks easier you probably want to wrap it in script file):

[image]

BTW: QtCreator's QBS profiles are direct copies of your build Kits configuration (set in Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits) so if you need to tune it you should do it there.

Comment: First I need to create qbs profile from commandline. And then use the existing profile in qtcreator, not vice versa.

Comment: Is your profile impossible to duplicate via QtCreator's Kits settings? I got following problem: QtCreator kept compiling my C++ with gcc, not g++. It apeared that my Kits were broken in the first place.